# How do I modify this code to allow a different element to trigger the event?

Tags: jquery

#### HTML

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>
            HEADER
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">li3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">li2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">li3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function () {
        if ($('ul', this).is(":hidden")) {
            $('ul', this).slideDown("slow");
        }
        else {
            $('ul', this).slideUp("slow");
        }
    }
);
});
```

I only want `slideUp()`, `slideDown()` to be reached if the `<h2>` is clicked.  Currently, both are called if any `<li>` is clicked.

How can I fix this?

Comment: why don't you apply click on `h2` instead of `li`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('h2').click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. TY! .next('ul') selects the first occurrence of ul after h2?

Comment: Yes, it selects the next element if it is a `ul`. You could omit the `ul` there, I just placed it there to ensure it is the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it triggered when the `h2` is clicked, shouldn't you do?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('h2').click(function () {
        if ($('ul', this).is(":hidden")) {
            $('ul', this).slideDown("slow");
        }
        else {
            $('ul', this).slideUp("slow");
        }
    }
);
});
```

Comment: The `ul` is not a child of `h2`, so that selector inside of the `click()` will not work.

Comment: @alex You are absolutely right, I didn't look it through carefully enough. +1 to your answer.